# Match returning 100 instead of actual value

Tags: javascript, arrays, match

I have an array that I'm cycling through. For each value in the array, I'm analyzing it and then shunting the value off into another array based on which conditions it meets. For the purpose of this question, though, I'm simply trying to count how many periods are in the current array item.

Here's the relevant part of the code I'm trying to use:

```
for(i = 0; i < (sortarray.length) -1; i++)
 {
  var count = (sortarray[i].match(/./g)||[]).length;
  console.log(count + ' periods found in name' + sortarray[i]);
  if (count > 1)
  {
   alert('Error: One or more filenames contain periods.');
   return;
  }
  else ...
```

Most values are filenames and would have a single period, whereas folder names would have no periods. Anything with more than 1 period should pop up an alert box. Seems simple enough, but for some reason my variable keeps returning 100 instead of 1, and therefore the box always pops up.

**Is there a better way to count the dots in each array value?**

Comment: You need to count real dot `\.`. Simple `.` is a reserved operator. It means: any character...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your regexp. The dot (.) means any char. Furthermore (since you are using `g` option) your regex will match the whole string.

That's why you're getting 100: **`length` is being called on your full string**.

Thus you should escape dot so that it will really look for dots instead of any char.

```
sortarray[i].match(/\./g)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that logic you can just compare the first index of `.` and last index of `.`, if they are not equal that means the filename has more then one `.`

```
for(i = 0; i < (sortarray.length) -1; i++)
 {
  if (sortarray[i].indexOf(".")!=sortarray[i].lastIndexOf("."))
  {
   alert('Error: One or more filenames contain periods.');
   return;
  }
}
```

Comment: This would work if I only needed a Yes/No check but I actually needed the count of periods as well.